# styles when merging shapefiles in qgis

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sld, merge

Trying to create something for mapstory.org
It wants it in all one shapefile.
So I create a polygons and lines (with time attributes) in qgis 1.8
Then merge them all into one shapefile, how can you save the styles of all those polygons and lines into one .sld, how do you create an sld file that will have the info for all those merged polygons and lines?

Comment: it's not really clear how your stuff should look alike (screenshots?). But as i understand, you want to  style the layer by some attribute (what you call "different polygons") AND some time-category or whatever, right? Did you already try to achieve this on your merged layer with the "Rule Based" styling from scratch? Cause merging styles with diverging infos on the same aspect can't work.

Comment: is not the style by attribute in worried about right now, mapstory wants one merged shapefile, so how do you do that and also give it only one style file? that will have the style for all the different polygons?

Comment: i thought you already merged your different shapes, no? As i said,it's hard to imagine what you are after without any knowledge of your data. Do your polygons change position over time, or do they just change attribute values and what do you want to show at all? Sorry, too little und unstructured info so far.

Comment: merging ( by Data management tools > merge shapefiles to one) removes all styling, that the 'problem'

Comment: well, thats why i proposed you to style your merged layer in my first comment. And as i only can guess that the same attribute in your different original layers is styled different as well, i suggested to try the "Rule Based"-Styling, cause there you can set a style based on multiple attributes. Please tell which part of this you do not understand, otherwise we will run in circles.

Comment: i think what your suggesting i may have to do a later point, Im not sure how to create different layers some polygons some lines and then put them into one layer, so that i could then style them by attribute

Comment: i think, i tend to give up. now, you start telling of lines as well, which is a completely different story. before, you only had polygons. Again, if you don't start to put all your facts on the table, none will be able to help you. I think, your problem is not about styling layers, but about handling geodata in general, so please ask first questions first. Edit your question text and start to describe your project in a way, that ppl don't have to search the needle in the haystack!

Comment: thanks for your replies, if i knew the perfect question to ask... i wouldn't have to ask it

Comment: Its not about a perfect question. As long as you don't invest more energy in explaining your project, what things are input and what should the output look alike, i can't help! You think your problem is solved by merging .sld's. In this context, your question is perfect, but i doubt that it will solve your problem for logical reasons i tried to explain before. What you need is the description of a possible workflow to  reach a still not clearly described goal from still unknown source material.Tell what your features are about, what your attributes are, what the time attributes look alike etc.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to symbolize your data based on the attributes of the data. In this case it sounds like you'll want a different symbol for each time attribute.

In QGIS you can easily accomplish this by doing this:

1. Double click the layer name to open layer properties
2. On the Style tab change the dropdown in the upper left from "Single Symbol" to "Categorized".
3. Choose the column containing the data you'll be categorizing by.
4. Click "Classify"
5. You can then click "Save Style" and choose to save your newly created style as an .sld

Comment: Yes I guess I'll want different styles for time attributes but also for different polygons, but how do I get them all into one .sld file? (if not by hand)

Comment: A Sid file is a raster and not associated with a shape file at all. There is not "a"file that will symbolize your data in a "movable"fashion.  That is what the attribute data are for.

Comment: @BradNesom (s)he meant .sld (SLD), not .sid.  There may have been a spelling mistake somewhere or possibly just hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your attempt correctly, but you can **not** merge polygons and lines into one single shapefile.

See this explanation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Mixing_shape_types

Comment: good catch Andre.  Either the lines/polygons bit was added to the question later, or I just skipped over that part.